# Debugging big input in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

Unfortunately a program I wrote in C++ has a bug (or bugs), yet I can't deduce what it is since only a single output line doesn't match the expected output (the input file has 3K lines of input). I know which input line is the problematic, yet it's over 2K lines into the input file so debugging it manually isn't very efficient.
Is there any way to let the debugger run "alone" with the first 2K lines and stop exactly before trying to execute the problematic input line? I use Windows and eclipse but don't mind switching the IDE or switch to Linux if necessary.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some specific code in your program which detects the input and stops the debugger? ie an if statement which, when satisfied, will do ask the debugger to break.  In windows I used to use 'asm int 3' or DebugBreak() api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel!

Eclipse has powerfull feature `Enable condition` for breakpoint.

- Set breakpoint in your code
- Right-click on breakpoint - "Breakpoint properties"
- Check "Conditional"
- Write your condition when breakpoint should be stopped (you have access to scope and global variables)

Here is Eclipse help page. [Breakpoint Enable Condition](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-condition_option.htm)
 (with [screenshot](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F))

Answer (score 0):

Well, eclipse may well have advanced debugging features, and to tell the truth I do not know the first thing about eclipse, but FWIW you can easily simulate what you want.

What you have is:

```
for(i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i)
   process one line
```

Add a condition to check the line number and place a breakpoint inside it!:

```
for(i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i)
   if(i == 2000)
   {
       int x = i*i; //random line, just add your breakpoint here!
   }
   process one line
```

Comment: Might need to turn optimization off to preserve the "int x =" line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know exactly what line is problematic, just a dummy `if` statement which would check the contents of the line, and if mathces your problem line, do nothing - and put a breakoint at this line.